# caret package in R: how to split the data into 75% testing and 25% training when I have repeated measures?

Tags: r, caret

I have a data set of 401 participants but each of those participants has 1-3 observations so a total of 535 rows/observations.

If I just randomly split this data set of 535 observations into 75% training and 25% testing, the same individual could have all timepoints in the same data set while others could be spread across the test/train data sets.

I know that with the caret package, you can fold the data while considering repeated measures like so:

```
folds <- groupKFold(dataset$study_id, k = 5)

dataset <- dataset %>% select(-study_id)

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, index = folds, search = "random")

mod <- train(fat_mass ~., dataset, method = "leapBackward, trControl = fitControl)
```

However, this doesn't split your data into 75% training and 25% testing data, it just conducts the cross-validation. So my question is, how do I split the dataset at the beginning into 75% training and 25% testing while keeping repeated measures from the same individual in the same data set?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you convert your data to' wide format' where each row represents one of the 401 participants, and then select 75% of the rows with something like `dplyr`'s ```training_set <- dataset_wide %>% sample_n(nrow(dataset_wide)*0.75)``` to get the training set? Then use some kind of participant id to get the test set... ```test_set <- dataset_wide[!dataset_wide$id %in% training_set$id,]```. Then convert each back to 'long format' ?